# Virtual ComPort stops calling DataReceived after some time

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am currently stuck at a problem which I cant find any answer for. I am controlling a device that is attached to the computer via a Virtual-ComPort (USB). For this communication I use the SerialPort class in System.IO.Ports.

This is how I initialize the port:

```
SerialPort SerialPort = new SerialPort();
SerialPort.BaudRate = BaudRate;
SerialPort.DataBits = 8;
SerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
SerialPort.PortName = SerialPortName;
SerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
SerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 9;
SerialPort.WriteTimeout = 1500;
SerialPort.ReadTimeout = 1500;
SerialPort.DataReceived += dataReceivedHandler;
SerialPort.Open();
```

I set the received Threshold to 9 because I know that all the data I can receive is 9 bytes long and I want to minimize the number of callbacks. Can this cause any harm?

This does work really well in 99,99% of all cases. But after a random amount of time/commands (typically after several thousand operations) I don't get a callback when data is send to the PC. The DataReceived handler is just not called in these cases. I checked this by adding a Debug.WriteLine("Callback received!") at the very beginning of the dataReceivedHandler.

I am sure the data is send by the device I like to control. What is the cause of this seemingly "random" behavior and how can I fix it?

I am grateful for any suggestions.

Best
Nano

Comment: Verify that data is really sent using PortMon http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx Ensure that `dataReceivedHandler` is fast and doesn't hang from some reason.

Comment: Also, test the same program with real COM port or another virtual COM port model. Many USB COM port emulations are known as buggy and unstable.

Comment: What baud rate are you running at in test? If possible, can you run at a different baud rate with better stability?

Comment: Thanks Alex! Does PortMon always recognize the incoming data? Does it also recognize the incoming data if the virtualization is buggy? How can I check if the virtualication is buggy? It is done by a third-party driver so I can't change this. For testing purposes the `dataReceivedHandler` does nothing but write the debug line and set an `ManualResetEvent`that allows the program to keep running (as it is waiting for the callback to occur). This should be fast enough any day! Thanks for the tipp with the real com-port. I can control the device via RS485 as well (at least for testing purposes).

Comment: @Tremmors: Thanks for the help. Currently I am running this at 57600 baud. I checked earlier to change this to other values (like 9600)but this didn't seem to have any effect. I think this is irrelevant due to the fact that this is a virtual Com-Port and not a regular one?

Comment: Regarding COM port parameters - they must match the device specification. PortMon works only in 32 bit OS, it is quite reliable. To know whether given USB emulation is OK, just try different emulations and real COM port. If problem exists only on specific model, it may be this emulation problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using ReceivedBytesThreshold is a convenience, but it only works when the Sun is shining and you've got a stiff breeze in your back.  You are skipping the things you need to do to ensure it *can* work:

- You need to implement flow control so there is no scenario where the device can overflow the input buffer.  Even though modern machines are plenty fast enough to support a high baudrate, they cannot guarantee that they are *always* fast enough.  Losing the processor for many hundreds of milliseconds is very possible.  You should always set the Handshake property so this can never happen.  The proper value depends on what the device supports, always start with Handshake.RequestToSend if you don't know.
- Never checking for errors is pretty much a guarantee that you cannot diagnose a mishap like this.  Implementing the ErrorReceived event handler is **not** optional.  It is the only way you can diagnose mishaps, like a UART or device driver input buffer overflow, the kind that cause data loss and cause the kind of trouble you are trying to troubleshoot.
- ReceivedBytesThreshold always gives you a synchronization problem.  You have to make sure that you start listening at just the right time, in between two chunks of 9 bytes.  That is of course pretty hard to do if you have no control over the startup order of your program vs the device, you rarely do.  A decent protocol always gives you a way to synchronize, typically with a dedicated byte value that indicates the start of a message.  Once you have that, the value of the ReceivedBytesThreshold completely disappears.

Start with the ErrorReceived event so you *know* when things go wrong.  Shopping for another USB emulator also ought to be high on your list of possible workarounds, drivers for them are generally pretty cruddy.